# Create timeslots with break periods

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a Calendar that sets availability by time slots with break periods.

I have two input data

1. The base start and end time. Example:

   ```
   [{startTime: '07:00', endTime '21:00'}]
   ```
2. The break periods. Example:

   ```
   [{startTime: '08:00', endTime:'08:30'},
    {startTime: '10:00', endTime:'10:30'},
    {startTime: '12:00', endTime:'13:00'},
    {startTime: '15:00', endTime:'15:30'},
    {startTime: '18:00', endTime:'19:00'}]
   ```

I need to breakdown the time slots depending on the base start and end time  AND the break periods.

Example given the input data above, I want to get.

```
   [{startTime: '07:00', endTime: '07:59'}, 
    {startTime: '08:31', endTime: '09:59'},
    {startTime: '10:31', endTime: '11:59'},
    {startTime: '13:01', endTime: '14:59'},
    {startTime: '15:31', endTime: '17:59'},
    {startTime: '19:01', endTime: '21:00'}]
```

Comment: You will need to loop through your break periods to produce a result data set.  You will have one more work time period than you have break time period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reduce function helps manage the data transformation. I used a separate function to add/subtract the time

```js
function getTimeFrom(time, diff) {
  time = time.split(":");
  let h = +time[0], m = +time[1]
  if (time[1] == "00" && diff < 0) {
    m = 60 + diff;
    h -= 1;
  } else m += diff;
  return ("0" + h).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + m).slice(-2)
}

let worktime = [{startTime: '07:00', endTime: '21:00' }], breaktime = [{startTime: '08:00', endTime:'08:30'},
 {startTime: '10:00', endTime:'10:30'},
 {startTime: '12:00', endTime:'13:00'},
 {startTime: '15:00', endTime:'15:30'},
 {startTime: '18:00', endTime:'19:00'}]

let workdetail = breaktime.reduce((b, a, i) => {
  if (i === 0) b[0].finalEndTime = b[0].endTime // save the value
  b[i].endTime = getTimeFrom(a.startTime, -1)
  a.startTime = getTimeFrom(a.endTime, 1)
  if (i === breaktime.length - 1) {
    a.endTime = b[0].finalEndTime; // our final end time for the day
    delete b[0].finalEndTime // remove it
  }
  b.push(a);
  return b;
}, worktime)

console.log(workdetail)
```